# Conditional expectation of X | Y > 0 for a bivariate joint normal

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Given $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with a bivariate normal distribution how can I calculate the expectation of $X | Y > 0$.

I tried:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} f_{[X|Y]} dx\, dy
$$

Where
$$
f_{[X|Y]} = \frac{f_{[XY]}}{f_{[Y]}}
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Do you have more information about the bivariate normal distribution? (means, variances, correlation)

Comment: I'm defining the distribution pdf as:
$$ f_{[XY]} = 
{\frac {1}{2\,\sigma_{{X}}\sigma_{{Y}}\pi}{{\rm e}^{{\frac { \left( y-
\mu_{{Y}} \right) ^{2}{\sigma_{{X}}}^{2}-2\,\rho\,\sigma_{{Y}} \left( 
y-\mu_{{Y}} \right)  \left( x-\mu_{{X}} \right) \sigma_{{X}}+{\sigma_{
{Y}}}^{2} \left( x-\mu_{{X}} \right) ^{2}}{2\,{\sigma_{{X}}}^{2}{
\sigma_{{Y}}}^{2} \left( \rho-1 \right)  \left( \rho+1 \right) }}}}{
\frac {1}{\sqrt {-{\rho}^{2}+1}}}}
$$

Comment: Are you asking for a general expression for the conditional expectation $E[X \mid Y>0]$ in terms of those parameters, or do you have a particular choice of those parameters that you are interested in?

Comment: In general, $$E[X \mid Y>0] = E[X \mathbf{1}_{Y>0}] / P(Y>0) = \frac{\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_0^\infty x f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dx \, dy }{ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_0^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dx \, dy},$$ but computing these things can be difficult depending on what the parameters are.

Comment: Thank you! yes,  this what I'm looking for. It seems indeed difficult to find a general expression.

Comment: Sorry, both integrals in my previous comment should be $dy \, dx$; I wrote the order incorrectly.

Comment: Could you please provide some more context on the formula you provided (a link or a book chapter to read on how to compute conditional expectations in general)

Comment: You are computing a conditional expectation with respect to an event (namely $\{Y>0\}$) so [this Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_an_event) is relevant.